# How to monitor success or failure of attempts to modify security settings or permissions in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, audit, amazon-iam

In AWS console, I can assign an IAM user  to  a group whose permissions is defined by associated policies.

The credential report in IAM seems to only report some basic attributes of IAM each user and its last login time (inferred from various fields such as `password_last_used` and `access_key_1_last_used_date`). But it does not tell me the group or role level information.

Is there any way I can monitor any attempt, success or otherwise to change these permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CloudTrail](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/) lets you monitor all API calls to AWS. This will do what I think you want. In their words

> AWS CloudTrail is a service that enables governance, compliance,
>   operational auditing, and risk auditing of your AWS account. With
>   CloudTrail, you can log, continuously monitor, and retain events
>   related to API calls across your AWS infrastructure. CloudTrail
>   provides a history of AWS API calls for your account, including API
>   calls made through the AWS Management Console, AWS SDKs, command line
>   tools, and other AWS services. This history simplifies security
>   analysis, resource change tracking, and troubleshooting.

[AWS Config](https://aws.amazon.com/config/) is similar, in that it lets you monitor and version control configurations of AWS resources. In their words

> AWS Config is a service that enables you to assess, audit, and
>   evaluate the configurations of your AWS resources. Config continuously
>   monitors and records your AWS resource configurations and allows you
>   to automate the evaluation of recorded configurations against desired
>   configurations. With Config, you can review changes in configurations
>   and relationships between AWS resources, dive into detailed resource
>   configuration histories, and determine your overall compliance against
>   the configurations specified in your internal guidelines. This enables
>   you to simplify compliance auditing, security analysis, change
>   management, and operational troubleshooting.

There are also third party tools, paid and open source, that provide similar services with better user interfaces, or user interfaces to these services.